# How to replace mutiline pattern space in sed

Tags: sed

I have a data which is shown like below in a file test.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Sample.test.value;
namespace Sample.test {

  class testclass{  

    public testclass(){


    }
  }
}
```

I want the output to be

```
namespace Sample.test {
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using value;
  class testclass{  

    public testclass(){


    }
  }
}
```

This i want to achieve only by using sed

I tried below sed script and able to copy and paste the using inside namespace

```
/^using/{
 H
 d
}
/^namespace/{
 G
}
```

But unable to replace the namespace in using statement. Here in this example I took an example as "Sample.test" namespace. But it real case it can be anything.

Comment: IMHO, I think this would be not trivial even in a real programming language. Especially if your sample data doesn't show all the corner cases your real data contains. Trying to do this in `sed` is like having to do it with both hands tied behind your back. I hope someone can prove me wrong. Good luck.

Comment: Shelter, Thanks for replaying. Can you give a solution only with the above explained case. Because as of now my all files contain only those cases. I want a generic solution in terms of namespace. This solution will really help me.

Comment: `/^using/{s/^/ /;H;d;};/^namespace/{G;:a;s/^\(\([^ ]*\) {.*using \)\2\./\1/;ta;N;s/\n\n/\n/g;}`

Comment: @jhnc any chance you can post (short) explanation - may be as answer - how does your solution work ?

Comment: @jhnc can you please explain in the answer section your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sed script transforms your test data but will need alteration if your files contain more than one using/namespace block, or if the whitespace is not identical.

```
# match using lines
/^using/{
    s/^/ /  # prepend whitespace 
    H       # append to hold
    d       # don't print (yet)
}

# match namespace lines
/^namespace/{
    G       # append the using block after namespace line

    # loop while we can strip a namespace name from a using line
    :a
    s/\(\([^ ]*\) {.*using \)\2\./\1/
    ta

    # read in next line and delete it if empty
    N
    s/\n\n/\n/g
}

# implicit print
```

The second `s///` command looks for the name that precedes a `{` (ie. `\([^ ]*\)`) followed by a `using` line with that same name followed by a period (ie. `\2\.`). The entirety of the match aside from the trailing `\2\.` is available as `\1` because of the initial set of `\(`...`\)` and replaces the original text.

**Note:** Using `\n` in the replacement is not portable. If using a version of sed that does not understand it, use an escaped literal newline:

```
    # ...

    N
    s/\n\n/\
/g
}
```

---

Building on @Jotne's answer, an equivalent awk version is:

```
/^using/ {
    # store using lines, along with a prepended space
    a[++i] = " " $0
    next
}
/^namespace/ {
    print

    # strip namespace name from using lines, then print
    r = " " $2 "[.]"
    for(i in a) {
        sub(r, " ", a[i])
        print a[i]
    }

    # delete subsequent line if it is blank
    getline
    if ($0) print

    next
}

# print every other line
1
```

The regex here (`r`) looks for a space followed by the namespace name (it should be `$2` on the namespace line) followed by a period. The `sub()` replaces any occurrences of this regex in the saved using lines with just a single space.

Comment: Can you please explain me what this regex doing  s/^\(\([^ ]*\) {.*using \)\2\./\1/

Comment: The first `^` was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` may do.  But not sure whats trigger the action and how it works on your real data.

```
awk '/^using/ {s=s"\n"$0;next} /^namespace/ {print $0 s;next} 1' file
namespace Sample.test {
using System;
using System.Data;
using Sample.test.value;

  class testclass{

    public testclass(){


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you save the namespace name after the first print, inside the `for` loop you can strip it from each using line before you print that

Comment: Not quite what I meant :) When namespace name is `Sample.test`, the output should have `using value;` rather than `using Sample.test.value;`

Comment: @jhnc OP does not post clearly why the field changes, so I leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/using/{s/^/ /;s/Sample\.test\.//;H;d};/namespace/{p;g;s/.//;n;/^$/d}' file
```

Gather up lines containing `using` in the hold space but first add a leading space and remove any `Sample.test.` strings. On encountering `namespace`, print that line, append the hold space, remove the leading newline, print those lines then fetch the next and if it is empty delete it.